# React Native IOS - Invalid Image path under key CFBundleIcons

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

We successfully submitted a react native ios app to AppStore through XCode. XCode prompted us an "Upload Successful" message. Few minutes later the AppStore Team sent us an email stating that our submission was a failure and they indicated what the error was. Please refer to the screenshot. Don't know how and where should we fix this. Any ideas?

[image: screenshot]